# Structure of login on parse

Tags: android, database, parse-platform, parse-server

I am migrating and old android application built on parse, to parse server hosted on heroku. I am building the database on mlab from scratch. Does anyone have any idea of login structure of parse? I want to know about structure of the parseUser. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Structure" ?? Here's the JavaDoc... http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html

Comment: https://github.com/parse-community/ParseUI-Android/blob/master/ParseUI-Login/src/main/java/com/parse/ui/ParseLoginFragment.java#L166  is from sample login to parse

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly simple. Parse handles both User and Session tables for you automatically. Basically on login, just use

```
Parse.User.logIn(USERNAME, PASSWORD).then(
   function success(user){
      (Some codes...)
   },function error(err){
      (print error)
   }
);
```

In the database, parse will create a session row that includes sessiontoken, pointer to the user and the expiry date of the token .

Comment: This looks like Javascript. Question said Android

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any idea of login structure of parse?

In the [Parse Android SDK](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/) to logIn a user on [Parse server](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server) there are 4 different structure:

To login a user with a username and password:

- [logIn](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#logIn(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
- [logInInBackground](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#logInInBackground(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))
- [logInInBackground with Callback](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#logInInBackground(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20com.parse.LogInCallback))

To login a user with third party authentication credentials:

- [logInWithInBackground](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-Android/api/com/parse/ParseUser.html#logInWithInBackground(java.lang.String,%20java.util.Map))

There are 2 popular way, synchronous way or [asynchronous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony_(computer_programming)) way:

```
ParseUser.logIn(username, password); // Synchronous way
ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, myLogInCallback);  // Asynchronous way
```

For example with the synchronous way:

```
try {
    ParseUser.logIn(username, password);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // if login failed, for some reason parse throw an ParseException
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;
}
```

For example with the asynchronous way:

```
ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
        if (user != null) {
            // Yes ! The user is logged in.
        } else {
            // if login failed, look at the ParseException to see what happened.
        }
    }
);
```

I hope my answer was helpful